# How to store irregular shapes as a UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage

I used this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/ZaidPathan/ZImageCropper) to make an image cropper that could crop images into irregular shapes. As of right now, I have implemented this repository and am able to crop UIImages in irregular shapes as depicted in the link.

In its current state, the cropper uses a UIBezierPath and a CAShapeLayer to take a normal (rectangular) UIImage and cut out the parts not included within the shape. Due to the fact that I am trying to store this UIImage in a database, I need it to be stored as just a UIImage and not have to also store the CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath that crop the image.

Is there a way to make this cropped section into a UIImage that is an irregular shape? If not, is there an alternative way of cropping a photo using user-drawn paths like shown in the link above that will allow for it to be stored as an irregularly shaped UIImage?

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking two totally different questions.  (1) How do I use code written by somebodye else?  (2) How do I crop an image with bezier paths drawn by the user?

Comment: Sorry about that. I just edited it to try to clear up my question more.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this library completely. They defined one method where you can get image from Graphic context.

```
func cropImage(){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tempImageView.bounds.size, false, 1)

        tempImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.croppedImage = newImage!
    }
```

This is the method where you can get `UIImage` and utilize it as per your requirement.

Comment: Wouldn't that still require the use of the lines "shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor" and "tempImageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer?" Both of these lines are called in the button action. Without these lines, the image remains its normal shape.

Comment: @MitchKelly So you want cropped image when user leave the touch from selecttion?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. I want to be able to have the ability to have a single UIImage variable that when assigned to the UIImageView would show just the cropped portion of the image. For example, in the GitHub example, I would want to be able to be able to have UIImage variable named car that would look how the image looks after the users clicks "crop image" in the example gif. If I then had a UIImageView called carView I could simply write a single line such as "carView.image = car." This single line would show the cropped car. Does that make any more sense?